# VBA Code to add comment to changed cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add a comment with original data to cell where data is changed.

Ex: 4 of 7 gets changed to 3 of 7 in a cell. I need the comment to show 4 of 7 so I can see what the original data was.

Is there a macro that can be written to automatically insert a comment with original data to all cells that have been changed?

Comment: do you want this for a single cell or multiple cells?

Answer (score 1):

Say you are working with Cell A1

Before you change the value of Cell A1, store it in a variable myVal, then write something along the following lines:

```
Range("A1").AddComment
Range("A1").Comment.Text Text:= myVal
```